# Умножить каждый элемент списка в списке Python

Tags: python, list, кортежи

Как в ОДНУ строку умножить все элементы списка/кортежа на х? Должно работать с кортежами если возможно.

```
x = 100
l = ([1, 4], [3, 1])
#одна строка кода
print(l)
```

Вывод: ([100,400],[300,100])

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
x = 100
l = ([1, 4], [3, 1])
new_l = tuple([list(map(lambda num: num * x, lst)) for lst in l])
print(new_l)
```

Что здесь происходит: генератор создает список, в котором каждый элемент - список из кортежа `l`, преобразованный с помощью функции `map` (каждый элемент умножается на `x`). Затем этот список преобразуется в кортеж.

С форматом кортеж-список можете сами поиграться, заменив `tuple` на `list` или наоборот в обоих случаях.